# copied to clipboard jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clipboard

I want to copy content(text) from a `div` to my clipboard & show what I have copied inside an animated toast. Furthermore, I want to have a clipboard history. This how it supposed to look:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XRNi.gif)

That's what I've done so far     [Jquery](https://codepen.io/M4TERIAL/pen/vYLQKWX?editors=1111)

1. I can't create a toast with jquery animations and displaying what I have copied inside the toast.
2. Even though I have successfully copied content my consol says the statement is false
3. Clipboard history has a maximum amount of 10 items it can display (how to do that?!)

I don't want to use bootstrap since the content is only text phrases. I am also new to javascript that's why I am not sure if I can do what I want with clipboard js.

Comment: If you don't want to use Bootstrap, then why are you using `$.modal`?

Comment: You also do not need `try` and `catch` block for this type of thing.

Comment: the `catch` block is throwing error even though successfully copied.

Comment: @hev1 well this one is nice but i have to create a close button for it so whats why i did not use it